# Derby java sql exception

Tags: derby, java-ee-7

I am trying to start an application on Glassfish 4 server but it gives me some strange exception:
`Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.`
Could it be because I don't have SQL? I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the Derby Network Server, and have it listen on port 1527 on localhost (which is the default setting for the Derby Network Server, so no special configuration is required to achieve that host and port).

You can find the instructions for starting the Derby Network Server here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/adminguide/tadmincbdjhhfd.html

If you are just getting started with Derby, you can learn more here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/

Comment: Thank you! I just started the web server and deployed my application. But now the entities I had all blow up. Is there some way to import my current entities into database tables?

Comment: A Derby database can be located in a folder anywhere on your hard disk; it sounds like you have created multiple databases with the same name, some empty, some with tables and data that you have already created. Once you decide which database you want to use as your permanent database, you can use the import/export system procedures to copy data from the others: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/adminguide/cadminimport16245.html