# Hibernate-Derby Database

Tags: java, hibernate, derby

I am using Hibernate with derby database, My configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/test;create=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">derby</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">derby</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update </property>
    <mapping resource="admin.cfg.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**admin.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.bean.Lecturer" table="lecturer">

        <id name="ID" type="int">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" column="FName" type="string"/>
        <property name="lastName" column="LName" type="string"/>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Main method**

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
static Configuration cfg = null;
    static SessionFactory factory = null;
    static Session s = null;
        try {

            cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
            s = factory.openSession();
            if (s != null) {
                System.out.println("Ok");
                Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
            Lecturer l = new Lecturer();
            l.setFirstName("Suresh");
            l.setLastName("R");
            s.save(l);
            t.commit();
            } else {
                System.out.println("NOt Ok");
            }
        } catch (Exception z) {
            System.out.println("Hibernate Connection Exception" + z);
        } finally {
            try {

            } catch (Exception z) {
                System.out.println("Hibernate Connection closing Exception" + z);
            }
        }

    }
```

**My Error is**

> Hibernate Connection Exception org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection 8285
>   [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 40000, SQLState: 08001 8285
>   [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.

Comment: Regarding "Connection refused: connect" -- see this  answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31575616/193453